# How to verfiy a package downloaded from github on Alpine without allowing untrusted

Tags: docker, symfony, apk, alpine-linux

I am trying to install symfony framework from it's Github [repository](https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/releases/tag/v5.4.11).

So, I am adding the apk file to my local machine and try to install it but I am getting the following error:

**Error**

```bash
#10 0.245 ERROR: /tmp/symfony-cli_5.4.11_x86_64.apk: UNTRUSTED signature
```

**Install Script**

```bash
SYMFONY_CLI_VERSION="5.4.11"
SYMFONY_ARCH="x86_64"

wget -O /tmp/symfony-cli_${SYMFONY_CLI_VERSION}_${SYMFONY_ARCH}.apk "https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/releases/download/v${SYMFONY_CLI_VERSION}/symfony-cli_${SYMFONY_CLI_VERSION}_${SYMFONY_ARCH}.apk"
apk add --repositories-file=/dev/null --no-network --no-cache "/tmp/symfony-cli_${SYMFONY_CLI_VERSION}_${SYMFONY_ARCH}.apk"
```

I've tried to install the related `.apk.pem` file, base64 decode it, get a public RSA key from the decoded cert and add it to `"/etc/apk/keys/${SYMFONY_CLI_VERSION}_${SYMFONY_ARCH}@symfony-1C204ECEF7BED6AB.rsa.pub"` but the error still the same.

I've noticed that the file name in /etc/apk/keys/ contains the wrong fingerprint but I am not sure how to get it from resources that I have or even if it causing the problem.

if I add `--allow-untrusted` to the`apk add` command it will work. My question is How can I verfiy the downloaded file and install it without allowing untrusted?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont follow the manual?
https://symfony.com/download#step-1-install-symfony-cli

```
sudo apk add --no-cache bash
curl -1sLf 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/symfony/stable/setup.alpine.sh' | sudo -E bash
sudo apk add symfony-cli
```

or just look into setup.alpine.sh to see how its adding the signature.

Comment: I did. I saw in the setup script that the public key and the fingerprint is being fetched from `dl.cloudsmith.io` and not from the github. So I was wondering how did they derive those from what is available in github release. in addition, it is not documented how can I pin the setup to specific version.